# How to take a derivative of an integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

How do you take the  derivative of an integral? For example, how could one take the derivative of this integral

$$g(y)= \int (f(y))dx$$

would it just be

$$g'(y)= \int (f'(y))dx$$
NOTE:F(Y) IS SOMETHING LIKE yx^2
If not could you please share a method to take the derivative of any general?

Perhaps this example is an awful example and you need two variables such as the integral representation of the gamma function. If so how do you stuff like that?

Comment: The symbol $y$ is being overloaded. Presumably you are familiar with the fundamental theorem of calculus?

Comment: I do remember the second part. I have seem to forgotten the first part

Comment: What does $\int f(y)dy$ mean?

Comment: If $f(y)=y^2$
Then $\int f(y)dy$=
$\int y^2dy$

Comment: @SamuelMorrison The fundamental theorem of calculus relates integrals to derivative, $\frac{d}{dx}\int_a^x f(t)dt = f(x)$. Notice that the $x$ relates to the bound of integration and not the variable in the integral.

Comment: Could you find d/dt of that integral?

Comment: Just recall the definition of the indefinite integral

Comment: Right now your question doesn't make sense. Give an example that you actually encountered. Learn how to solve that one and then generalize.

Comment: How to find the derivative the gamma function
@Mason

Comment: @SamuelMorrison Usually, $d/dy \int f(x, y) \, dx = \int \partial_y f(x, y) \, dx$. But to actually prove this, you need $f$ to be nice enough. The dominated convergence theorem is a strong tool here, as the asserted identity comes down to an interchange of limit and integration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $g(y) = \int_{a}^{b} f(x,y)\ dx$

$g'(y) = \int_a^b \frac {\partial}{\partial y} f(x,y) \ dx$

This is "differentiation under the integral sign" or the "Leibnitz integral rule" or "Feinman's trick."

This does require $f(x,y)$ and $f_y(x,y)$ to be continuous within the region of integration.

e.g.

$g(y) = \int_0^\infty \frac {\sin (x)}{x}e^{-xy}\ dx\\
g'(y) = \int_0^\infty \sin (x)e^{-xy}\ dx\\
g'(y) = \frac {-e^{-xy}(y\sin x + \cos x)}{1+y^2}|_0^{\infty}$

If $y > 0$ then $\lim_\limits{x\to\infty} e^{-xy} = 0$

$y>0 \implies g'(y) = -\frac {1}{1+y^2}$ and
$g(y) = -\arctan y + C$

which might not have been obvious from the original expression.

Answer (score -3):

$\int f(y) dy $ has no meaning.

Maybe you want to say

$ g(y) = \int_a^y f(t) dt $

In this case, $g'(y) = f(y) $.

Comment: What about $ g(y) = \int_a^k f(y) dy $
What would g'(y) be?

Comment: This is confusing. You can write that, but  the $y$ in $\int_a^y$ is different from the $y$ in $ f(y) dy$. This is why it is better to use a different letter as in my post above.

Comment: the $y$ in $f(y) dy$ is just a place holder. You could as well write $f(.)d.$

Comment: Sorry I forgot to change the number. I changed it to k now

Comment: $\int_a^k f(y) dy $ is not a function of $y$. It is a function of $k$.  So you should write $g(k) = \int_a^k f(y) dy $

Comment: I used y in $f(y)$ because i wanted to show that the input from $g(y)$ is also the input $f(y)$

Comment: But this is wrong.  $\int_a^k f(y) dy$ does not depend on $y$.

Comment: but it is a function of y. $f(x)=x^2$ is a function of x this is same thing. k is just some random constant, i don't want the intergral bounds to be dependent on the input

Comment: ${d\over dy }\left(\int_a^k f(y)dy\right)=0$

Comment: How can't you understand this? $g(y)$ takes in a value that is then pasted on to $f(y)$

Comment: For example f(y) could be yx^2 or anything

Comment: I see now I forgot to do dx not dy sorry

Comment: $\int_a^k f(y) dx= (k-a)f(y)$

Comment: $\int f(y) \ dy$ has meaning, it is an indefinite integral or an anti-derivative.

Comment: OK, but it is not a function of  $y$